# How can I declare parameters for callback function via summary?

Tags: javascript, types, parameters, jsdoc

So I want to add a callback function to my other function, but the issue is since I want this code to be public, I want people to know what parameters to enter and what their types are.

I've tried to do it like `Function<Event>` and `Function(ev:Event)`, but neither have worked, instead, it comes off as `any`.

This is my function:

```js
/**
     * Adds an event listener to track scroll events
     * @param {void<Event>} callback 
     */
    static addScrollListener(callback) {
        Input.scrollListeners.push(callback);
    }
```

To be clear, by "summary" I'm referring to the description of the function.

Comment: Documentation: https://jsdoc.app/tags-callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by adding the parameters, with the type after a colon in brackets, (name:Type)

Example:

```js
/**
     * Adds an event listener to track scroll events
     * @param {(ev:Event)} callback
     */
    static addScrollListener(callback) {
        Input.scrollListeners.push(callback);
    }
```